# Why CLR don't allow call the same assembly function when this assembly be loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clr

I see this from 《CLR via C#》 4th 587 page,here is sentence.

When an assembly is loaded with ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom or ReflectionOnlyLoad, the CLR forbids any code in the assembly from executing; any attempt to execute code in an assembly loaded with either of these methods causes the CLR to throw an InvalidOperationException.

I guess it's for thread safety?? please give me some advice for this question,thanks.

Comment: When you say "the same assembly function", can you be more specific? What *exactly* do you mean there?

Comment: @ Marc Gravell♦  i mean the  function in the same assembly,when an assembly is loaded

Answer (score 0):

A "Reflection-Only Load" is intended to allow you to inspect the assembly metadata without having to actually loading the assembly into a process for execution.

You can't call the function from a "Reflection-Only Load" because the assembly isn't actually loaded into the executable process.

**Further Reading**
[How to inspect assemblies with reflection before including them in your application](https://shazwazza.com/post/How-to-inspect-assemblies-before-including-them-in-your-application-with-reflection)

Comment: i actually just wanna know why i can‘t call the same assembly function when it be loading,just like lock

Answer (score 0):

No this has nothing to do with thread safety.  The entire point of "reflection-only load" is so that you can inspect the contents of an assembly without needing (or wanting) to execute anything. So by using this API you're explicitly declaring "I positively do not want to run anything here". As such, it is quite reasonable to anticipate that we can not, in fact, then run things.

Apart from avoiding a number of machinery parts needed to activate assemblies, this also avoids some (albeit unlikely) attack-vectors from module-initializers (yes, that's a thing - there's even a plan to add support in C#) running arbitrary code when all you thought you were doing was looking at the shape of an assembly.

If you want to execute things: don't use reflection-only load, quite simply.

Comment: ♦ Thanks,i understand.